# Inline syntax for integer CommandParameter in UWP XAML

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to use integer as `CommandParameter` in XAML as in

```
 <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save" Command="{Binding}" CommandParameter="1"/>
```

However, this will launch my `ICommand` with the **string** "1" as parameter. I know I can probably add

```
<x:Int32 x:Key="SaveCommandCode">1</x:Int32>
```

as resource and then use `"{StaticResource SaveCommandCode}"`. Is there a shorter inline syntax? I have tried `"{x:Int32 1}"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the shortest solution without using a resource is this:

```
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save" Command="{Binding}">
    <MenuFlyoutItem.CommandParameter>
        <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
    </MenuFlyoutItem.CommandParameter>
</MenuFlyoutItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

just convert the string in the command using int.TryParse() or int.Parse() - a literal will always be seen as a string.